# libcocos2dx library needed for Android project

Tags: android, cocos2d-x-2.x

Can anybody give the libary called libcocos2dx. I don't have installed cocos2dx but I need the libcocos2dx for a game to fix the project error. Please give me the project or give me a link from where I can download.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x and take the right version. It could be anything from v1.0 to v3.1, you need to know which one you need.

Comment: I need the library for android..Not the software for windows itself..Can I find the library there? in which folder?

Comment: There are different versions of Android's library, and you won't find a pre-compiled library. You should follow the readme to compile it yourself. If you use the wrong version, it's probably not going to work, because the Java <=> C++ bindings are not the same on different versions